# What is the desired way to access the masked functions, if called from within other function?

Tags: r, namespaces, environment

How can I force the package-defined function, if called from within my function, to use a specific function from other package, that is already masked?

---

I have written a function `myfun`, which calls function `expresso` from package `affy`:

```
myfun <- function(x) {
    expresso(x)
}
```

`expresso` will in turn call other functions, one of each is `normalize.AffyBatch.vsn` from package `vsn` and which ultimately calls function `intensity` that may reside in package `oligo` or `affy` (depending on which packages are loaded), in short:

```
> expresso
function (x) {
    normalize.AffyBatch.vsn(x)
}

> normalize.AffyBatch.vsn
function (x) {
    intensity(x)
}
```

I would like to be able to control, which version of `intensity` function is being called by `normalize.AffyBatch.vsn`. Packages will be automatically loaded in order that depends on data, so I will have no control on which version is unmasked for the current session.

---

My current solutions are:

```
myfun <- function(x, needOligo) {
    environment(normalize.AffyBatch.vsn) <- environment()
    environment(expresso) <- environment()
    if (needOligo) {
        assign('intensity', oligo::intensity)
    } else {
        assign('intensity', affy::intensity)
    }
    expresso(x)
}
```

or

```
myfun <- function(x, needOligo) {
    if (needOligo) {
        assign('intensity', oligo::intensity, envir=globalenv())
    } else {
        assign('intensity', affy::intensity, envir=globalenv())
    }
    expresso(x)
}
```

---

Here are the environments of the mentioned functions, just for transparency:

```
> environment(myfun)
<environment: R_GlobalEnv>
>
> environment(expresso)
<environment: namespace:affy>
>
> environment(normalize.AffyBatch.vsn)
<environment: namespace:vsn>
>
> getMethod(get('intensity', envir=as.environment('package:affy')), 'AffyBatch')
Method Definition:

function (object) 
assayData(object)[["exprs"]]
<environment: namespace:affy>
>
> getMethod(get('intensity', envir=as.environment('package:oligo')), 'FeatureSet')
Method Definition:

function (object) 
exprs(object)
<environment: namespace:oligo>
```

Comment: `help("::")` perhaps?

Comment: I do not see how it relates to my problem - I'm already using the `::` function in eg. `assign('intensity', oligo::intensity, envir=globalenv())`.
I would like to have control over what is called by package-defined function, so in order to simply use `pkg::intensity`, I'd have to edit that function's code (`normalize.AffyBatch.vsn` in my example)

Comment: I don't want to install these packages. You could try `myfun <- function(x) {intensity <- oligo::intensity; expresso(x)}`.

Comment: I've done that initially, but it doesn't work. From what I understand, since the `normalize.AffyBatch.vsn` is defined within the package, it will search environments for function names in this order: _namespace:vsn -> global -> loaded packages_, notably missing the execution environment of `myfun`